# switching on type in c# and VB - is this approach stupid?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, pattern-matching

I have inherited a codebase which contains a lot of upcasting.

I've got tired of all of the switch statements on types with ad-hoc casts inside the code.

I wrote a couple of functions for switching on the type of a variable and getting access to to that variable appropriately cast in the corresponding "case" statement.

As I am relatively new to dot net I thought that perhaps I was coming at it from completely the wrong angle.

If I'm not perhaps this will be useful to someone else.

NB `c#` specific answers are less useful as the code-base is mostly Visual Basic. I have posted `c#` code because the `c#` community is much larger here on stackexchange.

This is an example of the usage:

```cs
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<object> bobbies = new List<object>();
        bobbies.Add(new Hashtable());
        bobbies.Add(string.Empty);
        bobbies.Add(new List<string>());
        bobbies.Add(108);
        bobbies.Add(10);
        bobbies.Add(typeof(string));
        bobbies.Add(typeof(string));

        bool b = true;

        // as an expression
        foreach (var bob in bobbies)
            Console.WriteLine(
             TypeSwitch.on<String>(bob)
                  .inCase<Hashtable>(x =>
                      "gotta HASHTABLE")
                  .inCase<string>(x =>
                      "its a string " + x)
                  .inCase<IEnumerable<Object>>(x =>
                      "I got " + x.Count<Object>().ToString() + " elements")
                  .inCase<int>(x => (x > 10), x =>
                     "additional conditions")
                  .inCase(b, x => {
                      b = false;
                      return "non lazy conditions"; })
                  .otherwise(p =>
                      "default case"));

        // as a statement
        foreach (var bob in bobbies)
            TypeSwitch.on(bob)
                .inCase<Hashtable>(x => Console.WriteLine("one"))
                .inCase<String>(x => Console.WriteLine("two"))
                .inCase<int>(x => Console.WriteLine("three"))
                .otherwise(x => Console.WriteLine("I give up"));

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

and here is the implementation

```cs
public static class TypeSwitch
{
    public class TypeSwitcher
    {
        private object _thing;
        public TypeSwitcher(object thang) { _thing = thang; }

        public TypeSwitcher inCase<TryType>(Func<TryType, bool> guard, Action<TryType> action) {
            if (_thing is TryType) {
                var t = (TryType)_thing;
                if (guard(t)) {
                    _thing = null;
                    action(t); } }
            return this; }

        public TypeSwitcher inCase<TryType>(bool condition, Action<TryType> action) { return inCase<TryType>(p => condition, action); }
        public TypeSwitcher inCase<TryType>(Action<TryType> action) { return inCase<TryType>(true, action); }
        public TypeSwitcher inCase(bool cond, Action<object> action) { return inCase<object>(cond, action); }
        public void otherwise(Action<object> action) { this.inCase<object>(action); }
    }

    // for case statements with a return value:
    public class TypeSwitcherExpression<ResultType>
    {
        private object _thing;
        private ResultType _result;
        public ResultType Result { get { return _result; } }
        public TypeSwitcherExpression(object thang) { _thing = thang; }

        public TypeSwitcherExpression<ResultType> inCase<TryType>(Func<TryType, bool> guard, Func<TryType, ResultType> action) {
            if (_thing is TryType) {
                var t = (TryType)_thing;
                if (guard(t)) {
                    _thing = null;
                    _result = action(t); } }
            return this; }

        public TypeSwitcherExpression<ResultType> inCase<TryType>(bool condition, Func<TryType, ResultType> action) { return inCase<TryType>(p => condition, action); }
        public TypeSwitcherExpression<ResultType> inCase<TryType>(Func<TryType, ResultType> action) { return inCase<TryType>(true, action); }
        public TypeSwitcherExpression<ResultType> inCase(bool cond, Func<object, ResultType> action) { return inCase<object>(cond, action); }

        public ResultType otherwise(Func<object, ResultType> action) { this.inCase<object>(action); return Result; }
    }


    static public TypeSwitcher on(object thing)
    { return new TypeSwitcher(thing); }

    static public TypeSwitcherExpression<ResultType> on<ResultType>(object thing)
    { return new TypeSwitcherExpression<ResultType>(thing); }

    public static TypeSwitcher switchOnType(this Object thing)
    { return new TypeSwitcher(thing); }

    public static TypeSwitcherExpression<ResultType> switchOnType<ResultType>(this Object thing)
    { return new TypeSwitcherExpression<ResultType>(thing); }

}
```

### Edit 1:

Replaced delegates with `Action` and `Func`. Added extension method in case you like that sort of thing.

### Edit 2:

Use `Is` to check type of object

Comment: I'll say that I rather like the end result of your style and wouldn't mind maintaining it. Of course the glue is a little obscure looking until you see it in use, but once you do it all makes perfect sense. Just saw a similar sort of situation [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/222221/is-there-a-specific-pattern-that-this-data-processing-code-follows). I'm assuming this sort of upcasting is happening all over the codebase?

Comment: @JTrana - yes that is a similar problem. This could certainly be adapted to allow an iterable list to be passed in. In that case it might be worth building up the list of conditions then evaluating them at the end rather than evaluating them as I go. Perhaps I should go further and make this explicitly monadic.

Comment: With [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/018hxwa8.aspx) and [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549151.aspx) I don't think there is a need to declare delegates anymore. Also, `typeof(TryType).IsAssignableFrom(_thing.GetType())` could be substituted with `_thing is TryType`. And with that I think you can remove the null check before. Nice little utility!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion

```
namespace xx{

public static class TypeSwitcher
{
    public static dynamic inCase<T>(this object item,Func<dynamic> function)
    {
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(T))
            return function();
        else
            return "";
    }
}


}

using xx;

static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<object> bobbies = new List<object>();
        bobbies.Add(new Hashtable());
        bobbies.Add(string.Empty);
        bobbies.Add(new List<string>());
        bobbies.Add(108);
        bobbies.Add(10);
        bobbies.Add(typeof(string));
        bobbies.Add(typeof(string));

        foreach (var item in bobbies)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(item.inCase<Hashtable>(() => "one"));
           Console.WriteLine(item.inCase<String>(() => "two"));
           Console.WriteLine(item.inCase<int>(() => "three"));

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Because it doesn't provide a convenient syntax for switching on type or provide idiot-proof type safety which were my two requirements.

Comment: hope my solution was helpful

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and thank you for fleshing out your answer. However I don't see what advantage it has. 1. it down't provide access to a checked-and-cast object. 2. It doesn't allow the whole switch statement to be an expression. 3. It doesn't allow "guard" expressions. 4. Using "dynamic" throws away the very type checking I am trying to encourage.